# How can I allow unknown users to access my SQL (Azure) DB?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Apparently one must explicitly specify (whitelist) the IP addresses that will be allowed access to a SQL Azure DB. I want, though, to have N-gazillion* users that will access these tables for data specific to them.

- delusions of grandeur/megalomania

Will these need to first provide me with their IP address so that I can add it as a valid entry, or is there a programmatic way to do it, or some other workaround?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

It would be advisable to have some sort of middle ware access the db and not your clients directly.

However if you want any IP to be able to connect to the db just add this entry to the firewall list:

Azure Portal -> Databases -> Servers -> Configure and add the following rule:

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer (thank you!!), but it's amazing that with such a modern, good looking, user-friendly website as Azure, they still require you to type in these min & max IP addresses, rather than giving a simple "Allow any IP address" checkbox.

Comment: (Several months later)  It's odd though.  I have this "All access" IP range setup on my Azure database, but SQL Server Management Studio (and my webapp) refuses to connect, reporting that my "IP address is not allowed to access the server."

Comment: In my case, I had to use `1.1.1.1` to `255.255.255.255`.

Comment: "Microsoft . It all explains" - it's for such absurd judgments that one really misses having a down-vote for comments.

Answer (score 8):

How will your users be accessing the DB, via a Web App (front end) or directly (I assume you won't give users direct access to your DB?), if its via a Web App (presentation layer) then all you need todo is grant access to this IP address of the presentation layer/service layer (and if hosted in Azure its beside it).

SQL DB Azure has two types of access restrictions (more info here) "[Windows Azure SQL Database Firewall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee621782.aspx)"

- Server-level firewall rules:
- Database-level firewall rules

You could either open up all IP address 0.0.0.0 -  255.255.255.255 (not very secure) or come up with more finer grained policies based on the above Database firewall rules.

Comment: Access is from a Windows 8 / Store app; so each user will be accessing from their own IP address.

Comment: You could always go via a service layer (IMO that would be the best architecture, personally wouldn't have a Win8 App accessing a DB directly, services layer in between) Win8 -> WCF/Web.API-> SQL DB

Comment: @user728584 I found the Server-level docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn505712.aspx) but I don't see a way to configure specific ports. Is there a way?

Answer (score 8):

The only way is to do it is via SQL query. Azure shows only Firewall Server rules to be visible only on the portal but on database level the only way is via SQL.

```
-- Enable Allconnections.  
EXECUTE sp_set_database_firewall_rule N'Allow All', '0.0.0.0', '255.255.255.255';
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Login to azure Portal

    select your database subscription

        click on Tools

                Now there is option 'Open in VisualStudio' (click on it)

                    You can see "Configure Firewall" click on it.

        Add you new IP.

Done :)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you let them talk directly to your database (for example via SSMS) you need to enter their IP (or you can just whitelist the whole range). Usually they will use your database via your own API, then it's not needed to whitelist their IP addresses.

Comment: What do you mean by "use [my] database via [my] own API"? I want the client to call a method that connects to the DB and inserts the record.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I just read your other comment below. What I meant by 'your own API' is a service that is hosted on one of your servers, but I see that clients make the call to the database from their own PC. Keep in mind that it is usually a very bad idea to call a database from external sources: every client will need to know the password of your database (can be reverse-engineered), and if it changes, you will have to update ALL the clients. It's usually better to create a REST API or something like that to perform the database-interaction, and call that from your clients.