# Connecting Azure SQL database to ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, azure, connection-string

I'm using Visual studio 2015. I have created a database on Azure and connected to it and can see it connected in the SQL Object browser.

I have copied in my connection string from the Azure dashboard and set the firewall for the database to allow any IP address access the database.

My connection string is:

```
static string connString = @"Server=tcp:uvaluedb2.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=UValueDB2;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=XXXXXXX;Password=XXXXXXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";
```

It is not connecting to the database and i get this message:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

I can query the database in VS.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of those firewall settings?

Comment: This is a well documented (and annoying, for me!) security feature of Azure.  You need to go into the Azure Management webpage and either allow your particular IP address access to the database, or allow a range (or all) IP addresses to have access.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406663/how-can-i-allow-unknown-users-to-access-my-sql-azure-db

Comment: Mike & Juunas, thanks, I had this in my firewall settings though: All 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255. Cant seem to post up a picture here. Still getting the same error. Thanks.

Comment: Is this error occurring when deploying the website to Azure? If so have you set "Allow access to azure services" in the firewall settings?

Comment: James, No I am not deploying the website yet. I am trying to run it in visual studio with a connection to the azure database. I have 'Allow access to azure services' in the firewall settings on. Thanks.

Comment: The connection string seems no problem, I am thinking if there's any chance that the problem is caused by the code side, which used an different string. Could you debug and check what the string is when establishing the connection?

Answer (score 0):

> I have created a database on Azure and connected to it and can see it connected in the SQL Object browser.
>
> I had this in my firewall settings though: All 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255.

It seems that you give access to SQL Azure database from all IP addresses, which should enable you to access SQL Azure database from your application running on local. Please make sure if you specify the correct SQL server name “**uvaluedb2**” in your connection string. And you could [get Connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-develop-dotnet-simple#step-3--get-connection-string) from Azure portal.

Besides, please try to create new SQL Azure database and configure firewall rules, and then access it from your application to check if same issue will appear.