# How can i connect to azure sql from my local machine without adding it to firewall? Note - Public acess is turned off

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-network

I want a solution wherein I can connect my local machine and other's as well without adding IP address manually in the firewall as it is a time-consuming process.
Each time I have to update the IP address in the firewall.
I tried connecting Azure SQL Server to Virtual network by the service endpoint SSMS. Then access virtual network by VPN gateway but it's not working.

Comment: Your post doesn't make much sense. You're trying to connect to the VPN *after* attempting to connect to the SQL server? Isn't that out of order? Are your firewall rules set up to allow connections from the VNet?

Comment: Hello @Hitesh.K, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept(mark) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: did the error solved now?

Comment: Look at this post: [Accessing Azure SQL database from anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48751895/accessing-azure-sql-database-from-anywhere)

Answer (score 0):

You could set your local machines' IP range to the the SQL database firewall  to allow these machines to access the Azure SQL database:

- If you specify an IP address range in the database-level IP firewall
  rule that's outside the range in the server-level IP firewall rule,
  only those clients that have IP addresses in the database-level range
  can access the database.

Ref: [Azure SQL Database and Azure Synapse IP firewall rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure)

For example:
[image]

If you want access the SQL database through Vnet, you could create and add virtual network rule to the SQL database firewall:

[image]

For more details, please ref: [Use virtual network service endpoints and rules for servers in Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-sql/database/vnet-service-endpoint-rule-overview)

Hope this helps.